# How to find the keys in Blob object?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I would like to know what *keys* are included in the Blob object returned *Bucket.list_blobs()*

```
#!/usr/bin/env

from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket("xxx")

blobs = list( bucket.list_blobs() )

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob)
```

When I execute the above code, I get below result.

```
<Blob: xxx, flights/raw/201501.csv>
<Blob: xxx, flights/raw/201502.csv>
<Blob: xxx, flights/raw/201503.csv>
<Blob: xxx, flights/raw/201504.csv>
<Blob: xxx, flights/raw/201505.csv>
<Blob: xxx, flights/raw/201812.csv>
```

I have checked the [document](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html) but *list_blobs* section does not mention about information about the *keys*. I know there is *blob.name* from the [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/data-science-on-gcp/blob/master/02_ingest/monthlyupdate/ingest_flights.py#L150) . But what else is there and how can I list the keys?

I wish there is some thing like [keys](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) like in dictionary...

Comment: Do you mean: `print(dir(blob))` ?

Comment: Of course using the API documentation is the best method, but using `dir(object)` is quick and easy.

Comment: Oh my god ! This is so cool . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Following @John Hanly  's advice , I was able to see the available methods in the object using *dir* .

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env

from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()

bucket = client.get_bucket("elite-caster-125113")

blobs = list( bucket.list_blobs() )

for blob in blobs:
    print(dir(blob))
```

Now I was able to see what was available.

```
['_CHUNK_SIZE_MULTIPLE', '_STORAGE_CLASSES', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_acl', '_changes', '_chunk_size', '_do_download', '_do_multipart_upload', '_do_resumable_upload', '_do_upload', '_encryption_key', '_get_content_type', '_get_download_url', '_get_transport', '_get_upload_arguments', '_get_writable_metadata', '_initiate_resumable_upload', '_patch_property', '_properties', '_require_client', '_set_properties', 'acl', 'bucket', 'cache_control', 'chunk_size', 'client', 'component_count', 'compose', 'content_disposition', 'content_encoding', 'content_language', 'content_type', 'crc32c', 'create_resumable_upload_session', 'delete', 'download_as_string', 'download_to_file', 'download_to_filename', 'etag', 'event_based_hold', 'exists', 'generate_signed_url', 'generation', 'get_iam_policy', 'id', 'kms_key_name', 'make_private', 'make_public', 'md5_hash', 'media_link', 'metadata', 'metageneration', 'name', 'owner', 'patch', 'path', 'path_helper', 'public_url', 'reload', 'retention_expiration_time', 'rewrite', 'self_link', 'set_iam_policy', 'size', 'storage_class', 'temporary_hold', 'test_iam_permissions', 'time_created', 'time_deleted', 'update', 'update_storage_class', 'updated', 'upload_from_file', 'upload_from_filename', 'upload_from_string', 'user_project']
```

Thank you very much @John Hanley